# How to store out-put from a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, save, output

```
for(i in 1:na) {     
b1=which(IFUT[,1]==format(data1[i]))
b2=which(IFUT[b1,2]==format(data2[i])
b3=which(IFUT[b1[b2],3]=="12:30:00.000")
????????=b1[b2[b3]]
```

How do i store the output b1[b2[b3]] in a list for this kind of loop?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, make a list to store the result

```
list_res = list() #empty list
```

second, put the loop

```
#your for loop here
```

Each element of list_res, which is a vector ('cuz it contains 3 elements)
so, at the end of the loop, we make a vector to store 3 elements B1, B2, B3

```
#put these following lines in the for loop
sub_vector = c()#empty vector
sub_vector = c(B1, B2, B3) #one element in the list
list_res[[i]] = sub_vector # append it to the list
```

then, we got list_res as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Check out lapply functions.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html

Its output is a list of results, and it works faster than a for loop.

If you need to convert that list to a vector (which you probably will), look at the do.call function.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/concatenating-a-list-of-data-frames/

If this is all too complicated, then you should probably declare a vector and append onto it, just be sure to declare the vector outside the loop like:

```
VectorA <- c()
for(i in x:y){
#Your Loop + append to vector
}
```